# Solving recurrence relation using generating function's

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Solve the recurrence relation $$h_n=5h_{n-1}-6h_{n-2}-4h_{n-3}+8h_{n-4}$$ With initial conditions $$h_0=0$$$$h_1=1$$$$h_2=1$$$$h_3=2$$  EDIT:When I worked it out I got a solution of $$h_n=\frac{-13}{18}2^n+\frac{4}{3}(n+1)2^n-\frac{1}{4}(n+1)(n+2)2^n-\frac{1}{9}(-1)^n$$ which works for $h_0,h_1,h_2$ however not for $h_3$

Comment: For context, do you know how to solve it *without* generating functions? Either way, it helped if you showed the work and pointed to where you got stuck.

Comment: Um no I don't know how to solve it without generating functions, and everytime I solve it I get an answer that works for $h_0,h_1,h_2$ but not for $h_3$

Comment: Lookup [homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) and note that your characteristic polynomial $x^4-5x^3+6x^2+4x-8$ factors fairly easily.

Comment: Not sure if I'm just doing it wrong or just different, becuase I don't get that characteristic polynomial I end up solving $f(x)(1-5x+6x^2+4x^3-8x^4)=2x^3+x^2+x$

Comment: Not sure I follow your derivation, but shouldn't that last term be $-8x^4$.

Comment: I hope that $8x^3$ in your last comment is a typo for $8x^4$. If it's not a typo, it could be your problem.

Comment: yes it was a typo

Comment: But anyway what you should get is $(1-5x+6x^2+4x^3-8x^4)f(x)=x-4x^2+3x^3$. I think you got $2x^3+x^2+x$ on the right side by just sticking the given values of the sequence in as coefficients, but that's not the way the generating function method works.

Comment: No I got the $2x^3+x^2+x$ after simplifying some stuff on each side.  Must have been an error somewhere in the simplifying if that's what it should be.

Comment: OK. Try it again. Or edit into the question the work you did that got you to where you are, maybe someone will see an error in it.

Comment: Nah I went back and looked through my work and spotted the error, thank-you for all your help.